# Wordpress MiniOrange IDP is not redirecting back to SP

Tags: wordpress, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I have two Wordpress sites. I am using MiniOrange plugins in both sites. One of them act as SAML IDP and and the other as SAML SP.

Now issue that I am facing is, when I start SP-Initiated flow, browser is redirected to IDP which is fine. But after authenticating on IDP, browser does not redirect back to the SP. Instead, I am shown IDP's home page.

Now what I do is, in the new tab I again started SP-Initiated flow , since IDP's session is already there, this time I am correctly redirected back to SP.

So I am not entirely sure where the problem is, is it MiniOrange plugin or Wordpress?